# Can cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/storage/managedwriter NewManagedStream and NewClient be mocked for use in unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I'm trying to write a unit test to function that utilizes NewManagedStream and NewClient methods provided by cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/storage/managedwriter, I could not find a suitable interface name to generate mocks using mockery. I appreciate if someone out there share their experience on how to mock these methods in go unit tests. Thanks!

It tried generating mocks using mockery like:

```
counterfeiter -o /store/in/this/path/counterfeits cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/storage/managedwriter writerClientOption
```

Issue with this generated counterfeits is that `*managedwriter.writerClientConfig` is not exported.